# Blank space in php for each gallery

Tags: php, whitespace, image-gallery

I may just overlook sth. but I wrote a really easy gallery with the php code below. I always get a blank space with no picture an no div container in the second row on the first column. All pictures load and display correctly, i got no errors or warnings. I just have a blank space.

I tried to filter empty or hidden files and I changed the number images per row. But nothing worked. What else can i look for? And i tried to var_dump $images. Everything seems right there. 17 Pictures with the correct name and path.

my css just has a float:left to display the pictures.

```
<?php
$dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "gallery" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$images = glob($dir . "*.{jpg,jpeg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="con">
        <?php
        foreach ($images as $i) {
          printf("<div class='col-lg-4' id='gallery'><img src='gallery/%s' class='img-thumbnail'/></div>", basename($i));
        }?>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just want 3 pictures in a row with no blank space in the second row, first column

Comment: why dont you `vardump($images)` to see what you get, maybe you get some funny filenames as well

Comment: tried it an i get the exakt same number anf right file names of the images i display already. Nothing else. No funny file names nothing that is too much on the page.

Comment: where did you see it? On the webpage itself unless properly escaped and put inside <pre> tags some things may be missed

Comment: i formated it properly, but its the 17 pictures i want nothing extra nothing wrong. Each file name is correct.

Comment: I think one of the files is a little higher. If it is 1 or more pixels higher you'll get this problem. I suggest to give the image's a max-height.

Comment: Oh yeah. but now i need to equalise all pictures i upload XD well. Thanks. Problem is solved for now.